# Bootstrap full width slider issues

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I m using bootstrap full width slider.

Here is my code:

```
 <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">


        <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://s2.postimg.org/oxfpuzbll/home_slider1.jpg');"></div>

            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://s2.postimg.org/qk0c2gy9l/home_slider2.jpg');"></div>
 >
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://s2.postimg.org/4jjzlufll/home_slider3.jpg');"></div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </header>
```

Here is my [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ajbryjeL/)

When move one slider after that it showed white space and then move next slider.

May i know, how can i remove the white space?

Thanks,

Comment: Its **[working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ajbryjeL/3/)** Except you are experiencing that issue because the image is taking too much time to load, as per my view and from second round it goes on well.. May be the size of image is too big..

Comment: but.. i have to do this that one.. where you can change..?

Comment: Your last comment is not clear..

Comment: @saina just try with a small sized image. Then reply if it works!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: your fiddle working fine right.. so where you can modify my code?

Comment: I just ran your fiddle.. I haven't made any code changes.. Except from the fiddle I loaded `jquery.js` earlier than `bootstrap.js`

Comment: for me, it is not working...

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: actually, I can't decrease the size of my image.. and I need to avoid white space ..thanks..

Comment: decreasing size doesn't mean that reduce `height` and `width`, You can also decrease it by converting it into `png` using some photoshop, preserving the aspect ratio and quality of the image..

Comment: @saina take a look on this http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h

Comment: okay thanks.. but why my fiddle is not working/..

Comment: @Santhucool: I need full width slider.. thanks anyway..

Comment: ok buddy. Take a look on this it may help you http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-slider/

Comment: Your fiddle was not working because you were loading `jquery.js` after `bootstrap.js` from external file. There was option in **framework and extensions** to load it at first.. And thus you were getting console error saying **$ is not defined** which was obvious..

Comment: @saina please take a look my answer fiddle. hope it may help you!!

Comment: ok @GuruprasadRao: I removed jquery file.. but still it didn't work..

Comment: @Santhucool: I m already using your link only.. it has some issues...then only i posted...

Comment: @saina can you specify what issues you facing?

Comment: You should not remove `jquery` file instead you need to add it before any other `.js` file

Answer (score 1):

Solved!! Check this fiddle

Just changed the `jquery` file's version. Carousel needed `jQuery 1.9.1` or greater.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/5ok6fLcc/1/)